# how to feed data in batches TensorFlow CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

Almost all examples on github or other blogs uses `mnist` dataset for demo. When I am trying to use same deep NN for my images data I encounter following problem.

They use:

```
  batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
  # Run optimization op (backprop)
  sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: trainimg, Y: trainlabel, keep_prob: 0.8})
```

`next_batch` method to feed data in batches.

My question is:

Do we have any similar method to feed data in batches?

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at `tf.contrib.data.Dataset`. You can create an input pipeline: define the source, apply a transforation, and batch it. See the [programmer's guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets) for importing data.

From the documentation:

> The Dataset API enables you to build complex input pipelines from simple, reusable pieces. For example, the pipeline for an image model might aggregate data from files in a distributed file system, apply random perturbations to each image, and merge randomly selected images into a batch for training

EDIT:

I guess what you have is an array of pictures (filenames). Here is an example from the programmer's guide.

Depending on your input files, the transformation part will change. Here is the extract for consuming an array of picture files.

```
# Reads an image from a file, decodes it into a dense tensor, and resizes it
# to a fixed shape.
def _parse_function(filename, label):
  image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
  image_decoded = tf.image.decode_image(image_string)
  image_resized = tf.image.resize_images(image_decoded, [28, 28])
  return image_resized, label

# A vector of filenames.
filenames = tf.constant(["/var/data/image1.jpg", "/var/data/image2.jpg", ...])

# labels[i] is the label for the image in filenames[i].
labels = tf.constant([0, 37, ...])

dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)

# Now you have a dataset of (image, label). Basically kind of a list with
# all your pictures encoded along with a label. 
# Batch it.
dataset = dataset.batch(32)
# Create an iterator.
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
# Retrieve the next element.
image_batch, label_batch = iterator.get_next()
```

You could also shuffle your images.

Now you can use your `image_batch` and `label_batch` as placeholders in your model definition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Moreover, I would really apprecite if you or someone else can explain the same with a code.

Comment: using this method when I am trying to 
`batch_x, batch_y = iterator.get_next()

        # Run optimization op (backprop)

        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y, keep_prob: 0.8})`

it gives me an error saying 

`TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.`

Comment: You do not need to feed these variables with feed_dict anymore. You instead use your `image_batch` and `label_batch` variables in your model directly (i.e. as you did with placeholders).

Comment: then there is not batch processing... my machine got hung by doing so. :D

Comment: The batch processing is done by the iterator. Try for yourself to run `sess.run(image_batch)` what it looks like. You can run it multiple times, it will return a batch of images until the dataset is done iterating over the data.  Could you try `sess.run(image_batch)` to see if everythin is correctly set up ?

Comment: ok I got your point that in place of X which was my original input placeholder and Y which was my original input label placeholder now the place holders are image_batch and label_batch but what will be that training logic then? if I want to train CNN for 200 epochs and if I have 50 images. 

how the `sess.run()` can be written?

I tried sess.run(image_batch) it gives error saying

`InternalError (see above for traceback): HandleElementToSlice Cannot copy slice: number of elements does not match.  Shapes are: [element]: [250,300,1], [parent slice]: [250,300,3]`